# Regular Expression works in Regex101 but not Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
with open('names.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

twitter_pattern = re.compile(r"\s{1}[@]\w+")

twitter_match = twitter_pattern.findall(str(data))
print(twitter_match)
```

names.txt is a list of full names, phone numbers and twitter handles.
`\s{1}[@]\w+` should return only twitter handles, but returns an empty list. Everything seems to be [working fine in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6BEEHS/1), but not when I run this through Jupyter Notebook.

The content of the file is identical to the data provided in the Regex101 link:

```
Osterberg, Sven-Erik    governor@norrbotten.co.se       Governor, Norrbotten    @sverik
, Tim   tim@killerrabbit.com        Enchanter, Killer Rabbit Cave
Butz, Ryan  ryanb@codingtemple.com  (555) 555-5543  CEO, Coding Temple  @ryanbutz
Doctor, The doctor+companion@tardis.co.uk       Time Lord, Gallifrey
Exampleson, Example me@example.com  555-555-5552    Example, Example Co.    @example
Pael, Ripal ripalp@codingtemple.com (555) 555-5553  Teacher, Coding Temple  @ripalp
```

Comment: Readlines returns a list of string. You are converting it to string which is probably not what you expect. Instead simply read the file or apply the find all on each element of the list.

Comment: `{1}` doesn't actually do anything, and so does `[@]` since `@` is not a special character. Please also include `names.txt`'s content so we know what it looks like.

Comment: Right.  Change `readlines` to `read`, change `str(data)` to `data`.  Also, your expression can be simplified to `r"\s@\w+"`.  There's no point in `{1}`, and `[@]` is the same as `@`.  HOWEVER, even with `readlines`, this should have worked.  You're sure your strings are preceded by whitespace?

Comment: @InSync Okay, just added the content

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/error/textual content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste them here as text.

Comment: The original code works just fine for me.  There must be something about the data file.  I'm testing it with strings preceded by a tab (like he has), and followed by end of line.  All OK.  The matches will include the preceding whitespace character, but that's minor.

Comment: Just added a link @ThomasWeller hope that's helpful.

Comment: @KeenanMedley: a link to Regex101, not a link to a picture of Regex101. Press Ctrl+S

Comment: Post textual content as text. We don't want to retype those ourselves.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your help. Yes I'm sure. I just attached added what the content to the post so that you can see what the data looks like.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Okay gotcha, here it is: https://regex101.com/r/6BEEHS/1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`readlines()` reads the text as an array of strings.

The file

```
Hello
World
```

gives the array `["Hello", "World"]`.

`str(data)` is the textual representation of that array. In Python that's the text `["Hello", "World"]`. Note that the line break was consumed and interpreted as the start of the next item of the array.

In your case that means you get `[` and `]` as well as a lot of additional `"` and `,`, with the consequence that you no longer have a whitespace after the Twitter handle.

To fix your code, don't read the file as an array, read it as text instead.

```py
with open('twitter.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()              # instead of readlines()
```

Also, please don't make your Regex more complicated than necessary. `\s@\w+` is identical but less confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My apologies, just started learning Regex this week. 
One follow up question, it's returning only the twitter handles just like I need. However it's returning "\t" in front of each handle. For example it says, "\t@ryanbutz"

Comment: @KeenanMedley: `\t` is the tab character. You get that because you specified `\s` in the Regex, which is to find a whitespace and a tab is a whitespace.

Comment: @KeenanMedley: Try a non-capturing group and a group, like `(?:\s)(@\w+)`

Comment: Wow. If someone would comment on the downvotes, I might be able to improve my answer. As for my part, I can say that I tested this with a file containing the data provided by the Regex Link. I was thus able toreproduce the problem. I debugged it, found the cause and fixed it, IMHO. If that's not correct, then I'd like to learn where I was wrong.